# Symmetric Difference Relationship

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given sets $A\bigtriangleup B=\{x_1\}$ and $C\bigtriangleup B=\{x_2\}$ and defining $D=B\bigtriangleup \{x_1,x_2\}$, why does this imply that $C\bigtriangleup D=\{x_1\}$ and $A\bigtriangleup D=\{x_2\}$?

I've tried to draw Venn diagrams but I can't seem to figure it out. I think my issue is with the fact that, for example, with $A\bigtriangleup B=\{x_1\}$ how do I know if $\{x_1\} \in A\backslash B$ or $B\backslash A$?

Any help unpacking this implication would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’ve shown that symmetric difference is associative, you can do it with a straightforward calculation:

$$\begin{align*}
A\mathop{\triangle}D&=A\mathop{\triangle}(B\mathop{\triangle}\{x_1,x_2\})\\
&=(A\mathop{\triangle}B)\mathop{\triangle}\{x_1,x_2\}\\
&=\{x_1\}\mathop{\triangle}\{x_1,x_2\}\\
&=\{x_2\}\,.
\end{align*}$$

The other result is similar.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not particularly familiar with this operation, so that's a handy fact!

Comment: @GraphMathTutor: You’re welcome! (You may also find it helpful at times to think of $X\mathop{\triangle}Y$ as the set of things that belong to exactly one of the sets $X$ and $Y$.)

Comment: I'm reading a paper (that's not about set theory!) and they aren't showing any of their work when they make claims like this. Do you see why it is immediately obvious that the relationships stated above give us $D \cap B, (D \cap B)  \cup \{x_1\},(D \cap B) \cup \{x_2\}, (D \cap B)\cup \{x_1,x_2\}\in \{A,B,C,D\}$? I've been playing around with my set operations for hours and can't come up with the conclusion.

Comment: @GraphMathTutor: $$\begin{align*}B\cap D&=B\cap(B\mathop{\triangle}\{x_1,x_2\})\\&=\big(B\cap(B\setminus\{x_1,x_2\})\big)\cup\big(B\cap(\{x_1,x_2\}\setminus B)\big)\\&=(B\setminus\{x_1,x_2\})\cup\varnothing\\&=B\setminus\{x_1,x_2\}\,.\end{align*}$$ If $x_1,x_2\notin B$, then $D\cap B=B$, and $x_1\notin B$ and $A\mathop{\triangle}B=\{x_1\}$ imply that $A\setminus B=\{x_1\}$ and $B\setminus A=\varnothing$, so that $A=B\cup\{x_1\}=(D\cap B)\cup\{x_1\}$; a similar argument shows that $(D\cap B)\cup\{x_2\}=C$, and clearly $(D\cap B)\cup\{x_1,x_2\}=B$. I’ve not checked the details, but I expect ...

Comment: ... that the cases $B\cap\{x_1,x_2\}=\{x_1\}$, $B\cap\{x_1,x_2\}=\{x_2\}$, and $\{x_1,x_2\}\subseteq B$ can be worked through similarly.